# Using the android backbutton with Dojomobile and phonegap in worklight

Tags: html, css, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

Im creating an app (rather big one) with Worklight. When im testing the app in an android phone and press the backbutton it closes the app.. now i want it to go back one page. Right now the page navigation is with dojox mobile implemented system. this way:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton" data-dojo-props="transition:'fade',dir:'1',moveTo:'Contact'" class="buttonHem" style="color:black; font-size:1em;">Kontakta Oss</button>
```

is there a way to use the android backbutton without having to redo everything?

we have deadline in 2 weeks so there is really no time to redo the app with jquery mobile..

Answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about a hardware Android back button you have a WL API to override it's behaviour.
WL.App.overrideBackButton(function() { doSomething });
and WL.App.resetBackButton();

Comment: Do I have to write a javascript switch function for the page changing? or is there a "lazy" way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The back button functionality should work in Dojo Mobile. Looking at the documentation for ToolBarButton I think what you need to do is use a # in front of your next view for the moveTo attribute. In your example it would be moveTo:'#Contact' Take a look at the moveTo attribute in the doc below for more info.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton.html

Comment: This seems to be dojo 1.8 if I remember correctly worklight uses 1.7.2 right now. But ill try it.

Comment: The documentation seems to be the same for 1.7 http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton.html